# Listing Implemented Methods in Python Class

Tags: python, oop, error-handling

I am working on a piece of scientific code in which we want to implement several solvers and compare them. We are using a config file in which we can declare the name of the solver we wish to apply. As we are constantly adding new solvers, I've contained them in a class such that we can pull the name from the config file and apply that one with `getattr`, without having to add anything new to the code other than the solver method itself. I've not implemented any attributes or any methods other than the solvers in this class.

I've also implemented an error message in case the chosen solver doesn't exist. The whole block looks like this:

```
try:
    solver = getattr(Solvers,control['Solver'])
except AttributeError:
    print('\n Invalid Solver Choice! Implemented solvers are: \n' \
          + str(set(dir(Solvers)) - set(dir(Empty))))  # Implemented solvers
    raise
solver(inputs)  # Call the desired solver
```

This is convenient as it automatically updates our error handling with the addition of a new method. My question relates to the error message there. Specifically, I want to return a list of the implemented solvers and **only** of the implemented solvers.

It doesn't suffice to simply list the output of `dir(Solvers)`, since this includes a lot of other methods like `__init__`. Similarly, I can't set-subtract the results of `dir(object)`, since this still ends up returning a few extra things like `__dict__` and `__module__`. This is why I have the class Empty, which is just:

```
    class Empty:
        pass
```

I'm wondering if there exists a more elegant way to implement this than the kludgey `Empty` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is:

```
set(A.__dict__) - set(type.__dict__)
```

However, it will still return `__weakref__`. Instead, you can use:

```
set(A.__dict__) - set(type("", (), {}).__dict__)
```

It compares your class to `type("", (), {})`. This creates a new class object, like your Empty, but is a bit more subtle. For an example class:

```
>>> class A: pass
...
```

It gives:

```
>>> set(A.__dict__) - set(type("", (), {}).__dict__)
set()
```

And for:

```
>>> class B:
...  def f(self): pass
...
```

It returns:

```
>>> set(B.__dict__) - set(type("", (), {}).__dict__) 
{'f'}
```

You can do it with `dir` like:

```
>>> set(dir(B)) - set(dir(type("", (), {})))
{'f'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Explicit is better than implicit, and you may want to have non-solver methods in you class. The simplest explicit-yet-dry solution is to just use a decorator to mark which methods should be considered as "solver" methods:

```
def solver(fun):
    fun.is_solver = True
    return fun

class Solvers(object):
    @solver
    def foo(self):
        return "foo"

    @solver
    def bar(self):
        return "bar"

    @classmethod
    def list_solvers(cls):
        return [name for name, attr 
                in cls.__dict__.items() 
                if getattr(attr, "is_solver", False)]
```